# Pull to refresh ListView shows error for Android

Tags: android, react-native, pull-to-refresh

Description

When I use refreshControl with listview, header shows in error position, as pic:

[image]

The red region is pull to refresh header, but is shows over listview not the header of listerview.
When listview render all datasource, then pull to refresh UI could be normal, just when listview not render all datasource pull to refresh ui shows as pic as above.

Pull to refresh UI reference with Native UI Components 
but the same refreshcontrol with ScrollView no such issue.

Additional Information

React Native version: [0.33]
Platform: [Android]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `refreshControl` attributes

```html
<ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(data)}
        renderRow={this.renderItems.bind(this)}
        renderFooter={this.renderFooter.bind(this)}
        onEndReached={() => this._onEndReached()}
        onEndReachedThreshold={10}
        onScroll={() => this._onScroll()}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
            refreshing={goods.isRefreshing}
            onRefresh={() => this._onRefresh()}
            title="Loading..."
            colors={['#ffaa66cc', '#ff00ddff', '#ffffbb33', '#ffff4444']}
          />
        }
      />
```

Comment: Yes, I have use renderScrollComponent={(props) => (<ScrollView {...props} />) instead of refreshControl。Because I need to change defalut header of pulltorefresh listview header。with the same refreshControl, scrollview will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

@舒文颉

```
<ListView
                    initialListSize={5}
                    pageSize={10}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    dataSource={data}
                    renderRow={this._renderRow.bind(this)}
                    onEndReached={this._onEndReached.bind(this)}
                    onEndReachedThreshold={10}
                    enableEmptySections={true}
                    onScroll={this._onScroll.bind(this)}
                    renderFooter={this._renderFooter.bind(this)}
                    ref={ (listView) => {this.listView = listView;} }
                    refreshing={this.props.articleListRedecuer.isRefreshing}
                    onRefresh={() => this._onRefresh()}
                    renderScrollComponent={(props) => (<ScrollView {...props} />)}
```